# How can I import dependencies in flutter web?

Tags: flutter, import, dart, dependencies, flutter-web

I'm setting up a new flutter-web application but I can't add dependencies that I could do in flutter.

for example I want to add font-awesome-flutter to the project but get this error!

font_awesome_flutter: 8.5.0

Because font_awesome_flutter >=8.0.0 depends on flutter any from sdk which is forbidden, font_awesome_flutter >=8.0.0 is forbidden.
So, because salema depends on font_awesome_flutter 8.5.0, version solving failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since flutter-web is not still stable and its in technical stage, a simple way for using library in flutter-web which has been working for *me* is to **add the library resources manually**. you just need to copy everything inside the lib folder of the library in your own project.
in order to access the library's resources go to https://pub.dev/flutter and search for the library you want and then find the library's github repo in the about section.

Comment: Thanks,  it worked for me. I hope this answer help the flutter-web's community.

Answer (score 0):

> flutter_web does not have a plugin system yet. Temporarily, we provide
>   access to dart:html, dart:js, dart:svg, dart:indexed_db and other web
>   libraries that give you access to the vast majority of browser APIs.
>   However, expect that these libraries will be replaced by a different
>   plugin API.

Source:

https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web/blob/master/README.md

In short, Flutter dependencies are not supported by Flutter Web at this time.